# Put the second half of image bellow the parent section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put the first photo on the site in the same way as on the link: https://metla-reinigungen.ch/.

My website is on the link: https://filipcuric.com/stojan-05/index.

I want to make the first image on the second link to be positioned on the same way as the first image on the first link.

The code for that first section is:

```html
<div class="about-section section section-padding-bottom" style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(76,111,113,1) 0%, rgba(156,232,197,1) 100%);">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container" style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(76,111,113,1) 0%, rgba(156,232,197,1) 100%);">
      <ul class="breadcrumb" style="float: right;">
        <li>
          <a href="en/home.html" style="font-family: 'Secular One'; color: #fff; font-size: 20px;"><img src="assets/images/nove/uk-removebg-preview.png" alt="">&nbsp;&nbsp;English</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 order-lg-1 order-1">
        <div class="about-content mt-sm-50 mt-xs-50">
          <a href="index.html">
            <h1 style="font-family: 'Blueberry Days', sans-serif; color: #fff; letter-spacing: 2px;">
              cleanland.<span style="color: #fffbcc;">ch</span></h1>
          </a>

          <h2 class="title" style="font-family: 'Secular One'; color: #fff;">Professionelle und&nbsp;zuverlässige Büroreinigung in Zürich</h2>

          <a href="contact.html" style="background-color: #fff; border-color: #fff; color: #4c6f71; font-size: 30px; font-family: 'Secular One';" class="btn btn-primary btn-hover-secondary">OFFERTE ANFORDERN</a><br><br>
          <a href="tel:+41797555777" class="btn btn-primary btn-hover-secondary" style="background-color: #fff; border-color: #fff; color: #4c6f71; font-size: 30px; font-family: 'Secular One';">
                        +41 79 7 555 777</a><br><br>
          <a href="mailto:hello@cleanland.ch" class="btn btn-primary btn-hover-secondary" style="background-color: #fff; border-color: #fff; color: #4c6f71; font-size: 30px; font-family: 'Secular One';">
                        hello@cleanland.ch</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 order-lg-1 order-2">
        <div class="about-image">
          <div class="about-image-one">
            <img src="assets/images/nove/naslovna-06.png" alt="about01">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say 'positioned in the same way' do you mean the image has to be aligned to the right of the browser window? At the moment the only difference I can see is that you images appears more in the centre of the div with the classes 'about-section section section-padding-bottom'

Comment: I want picture to somehow overflow the green part and to be half in a green and half in a white section.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add possition relative to your image

```
.about-image-one {
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for help. This doesn't work in a way that I wanted. I want picture to somehow overflow the green part and to be half in a green and half in a white section.